# ChromeWebdriver sees website differently than I do (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a script that logs into my online grade book to look for any changes (new grades, etc). This is my code so far.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

def main():
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    # goes to the desired website
    driver.get('https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina')
    # searches for and clicks a button that drops down a menu in which link for login form is visible
    button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn.btn-third.btn-synergia-top.btn-navbar.dropdown-toggle')
    button.click()
    # searches and clicks login link
    agree = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'zmdi.zmdi-account.dropdown-item__icon')
    agree.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And there is a problem, I cannot seem to find a way to make webdriver see what I see. What I mean is that [I see the webpage like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqKGE.png) and webdriver sees the same webpage [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W2qD.png) also the source code is different. I've tried using undetected ChromeDriver with no success. This is my code using UC.

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def main():
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    # goes to the desired website
    driver.get('https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina/home')
    # searches for and clicks a button that drops down a menu in which link for login form is visible
    button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn.btn-third.btn-synergia-top.btn-navbar.dropdown-toggle')
    button.click()
    # searches and clicks login link
    agree = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'zmdi.zmdi-account.dropdown-item__icon')
    agree.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.execute_script("window.print();")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Has anyone had a similar problem and managed to solve it?

Comment: It's might be displaying differently because of the http headers or the user-agent reported by selenium.